# Multiple elements per single item in Riot.js

Tags: javascript, riot.js

How do you create multiple elements per single item without container element for the `each` attribute?

To be more specific, let's say I want to create a definition list which has expected structure as follows:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Key1</dt>
  <dd>Value1</dd>

  <dt>Key2</dt>
  <dd>Value2</dd>
</dl>
```

So, basically I want to do something like

```
<dl>
    <each each="{ item in data }">
      <dt>{ item.id }</dt>
      <dd>{ item.name }</dd>
    </each>
</dl>
```

But with the `each` element omitted in resulting HTML to make it valid HTML.
Please note that such `each` tag does not exist in Riot.

**Update:** It seems that especially for `tbody > each > tr` combination, the solution I've described above could work - empty `each` elements are moved before the table and `tr`s from inside are directly under `tbody`. However, there is a problem with context - `tr`s cannot access `item` variable which renders this case useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved with the `<virtual>` element, you should use:

```
<virtual each="{ item in data }">
  <dt>{ item.id }</dt>
  <dd>{ item.name }</dd>
</virtual>
```

http://riotjs.com/guide/#loops

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do this without nesting elements in your cells. Isn't it easier to do this with a ul and li's, something like:

```
<ul each="{ opts.data }">
   <li>{ id }</li>
   <li>{ name }</li>
   <li>{ description }</li>
</ul>
```

And use something like this in your stylesheet:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Here a demo using RiotJS: http://jsfiddle.net/rvanzon/3c8jjzw4/4/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently this is not possible - until possibility of removing parent custom tag is implemented.

See [issue #564](https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/564).